# Estimation of probability of the distribution of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the probability of the distribution of a discrete random variable $X$ which is defined $P(X=x)=y(5−)$ where $X\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.
Can anybody help me to find $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discrete random variable must satisfy the property $\sum f(x)=1$ where $f(x)$ is the probability $P(X=x)$ or in other words: the sum of all probability must equal to $1$.

Let's sum your probabilities to see what we get:
$y(5-1)+y(5-2)+y(5-3)+y(5-4)=4y+3y+2y+y=10y$

so now we know that the sum of our probabilities is equal to $1$ (since they said it is a random variable) and it is equal to $10y$ as well, so we have: $10y=1$ which gives us $y=\frac{1}{10}$

Note that for the continuous case you apply the same method but with the integral.

Answer (score 0):

$$y+2y+3y+4y=1$$

$$y=\frac{1}{10}$$